# Create new array from data.d.results

Tags: custom-javascript

I am trying to create an array with only the Name properties from a list in SP 2013.
I tried using the push method but it has not worked for me. My console prints out the names in an increment style.
First line has 1 name ,second 2 names, third 3 names and so on.

Here is my code:

```
function forLoop(){
  var siteUrl = "http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SPRestTest')/items";

      $.ajax({
          url: siteUrl,
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          headers: {
              "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
          },
          success:function(data){
            var arrayOfNames = [];
            for(var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++){
              var items = data.d.results[i];
              arrayOfNames.push(items.Name);    

            }

          },
          error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          },
    })
};
```

Comment: Where is your `console.log` where you are checking for the names / array?  I only see a `console.log` in the error handler.

Comment: Sorry I failed to include it

Comment: Can you describe where it is?  Is it the line immediately after the `arrayOfNames.push(items.Name);`?  Or edit your question to add the line where it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a better solution of what you are trying to achieve.

```
function forLoop(){
  var siteUrl = "http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SPRestTest')/items";

      $.ajax({
          url: siteUrl,
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          headers: {
              "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
          },
          success:function(data){
            var items = data.d.results;
            var arrayOfNames = items.map(function(o){ 
                                   return o["Name"]
                               });
          },
          error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          },
    })
};
```

Try executing on all browsers & Please mark this as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You describe a `console.log()` statement as printing the names in "an increment style", first printing one name, then printing two names, then printing three names, etc.

If the `console.log()` line that does that occurs immediately after your `array.push()` line, like so:

```
var arrayOfNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
    var items = data.d.results[i];
    arrayOfNames.push(items.Name);
    console.log(arrayOfNames);
}
```

then I would say that everything is working as expected, and the `push` function *is* working for you.

Let's follow what happens in the code:

- first, you declare a variable that's an array: `var arrayOfNames = [];`
- then you begin a `for` loop: `for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {`
- now you are in the first pass of the `for` loop, and `i = 0`.  You use `i` to get the index `0` item from the `data.d.results` array: `var items = data.d.results[i];`
- you push the `Name` property of that first item into your `arrayOfNames` array: `arrayOfNames.push(items.Name);`
- then you `log` the array, which at this point only has one item in it: `console.log(arrayOfNames);`
- now you are at the end of the loop, so the loop restarts, but increments `i` by one, so now `i = 1`
- you use `i` to get the item at index `1` from the results array: `var items = data.d.results[i];`
- you push the `Name` property of that into your array.  Now your array has 2 items in it: `arrayOfNames.push(items.Name);`
- you `log` your array, which now has 2 names in it.
- the loop restarts, but `i` increments to `2`
- you get the item at index `2` from the results array
- you push the `Name` property into your array, so now your array has 3 items
- you `log` your array, which now has 3 names in it
- etc

So you see, if the `console.log` line where you are checking your array occurs *inside* the `for` loop, then what you are describing is exactly what should be happening.

Besides putting that `console.log` outside the loop, the other minor adjustment I'd make to your code is to declare the `arrayOfNames` outside the scope of the `success` function, so you can use it elsewhere in your code.  Like this:

```
function forLoop() {
    var siteUrl = "http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SPRestTest')/items";

    var arrayOfNames = []; // declared outside the success function

    console.log('before fetching data', arrayOfNames); // will log an empty array

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                // change "items" to "item" - singular, because that's what it is, a single item
                var item = data.d.results[i];
                arrayOfNames.push(item.Name);
            } // end the for loop

            console.log('after looping', arrayOfNames); // will log only the full, completed array
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
    });

    // you can access the array outside the success function
    console.log('after fetching data', arrayOfNames); // will log the same array that the 'after looping' log did
};
```

Comment: Can also use `var items = data.d.results;` and  `arrayOfNames.push(items[i].Name);` - but six of one, half a dozen to the other.

Answer (score 2):

**You should try to avoid using ajax sync calls**.

Try to do whatever you want in the success callback if is posible.

```
function forLoop(){
  var siteUrl = "http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SPRestTest')/items";

  $.ajax({
      url: siteUrl,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function (data) {
        var arrayOfNames = data.d.results.map(function(item) {
          return item.Name;
        });
        console.log(arrayOfNames) // ['name1', 'name2', ...]
        doYourStuffWithArrayOfNames(arrayOfNames);
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      },
  })
};
function doYourStuffWithArrayOfNames(arrayOfNames) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to put in multiple values to that array, how would you do it? The return only seems to allow for a single one. And I don't mean in the context of `name[0], name[1], name[2]`, but like if you wanted to do `name[0], title[0], location[0]` and then do `name[1], title[1], location[1]`... can the `map` function do that?

Comment: I think i understand you. You want to return for each result more data. Then in `return item.Name` you should return an object instead. Something like `return {name: item.Name, prop2: item.Prop2}` and more and more... but yo use it it would be (in this case) `arrayOfNames[0].name` , or `arrayOfNames[0].prop2` ... an array of objects. Is what you are asking for?

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thanks - just had to make sure of that syntax on how to set, then grab those! Appreciated!